# I want to refresh the list without restarting the activity

Tags: android, android-volley

I have a method `extractRequests()` which extracts data from the MySQL database stored on webserver.

The activity contains one operation accept which is performed then that data will be removed from that list. Everything works well but the problem I am facing is I need to re-start the activity to see the data is updated. I want to make it real time so I don't need to re-start the activity every time to see the change instead it should be refreshed as operation is performed....

Below is my code

**ViewRequests.java**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class ViewRequests extends AppCompatActivity implements AcceptedCallback {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<UserRequests> Requests;
    RequestAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_requests);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.requestlist);
        Requests = new ArrayList<>();
        extractRequest();

    }

    public void extractRequest() {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        StringRequest jsonArrayRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "xxxxx", new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject requestobject = new JSONObject(response);
                    String success = requestobject.getString("success");
                    Log.d("Json success", success.toString());
                    JSONArray jsonArray = requestobject.getJSONArray("data");
                    Log.d("Json data", jsonArray.toString());
                    if (success.equals("1")) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            Log.d("Json data" + i + ": ", jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).toString());
                            UserRequests userRequests = new UserRequests();
                            userRequests.setUsername(object.getString("username").toString());
                            userRequests.setPickupaddress("Pickup address:" + object.getString("pickupaddress").toString());
                            userRequests.setDropaddress("Drop address:" + object.getString("dropaddress").toString());
                            userRequests.setImage(object.getString("photo").toString());
                            userRequests.setId(Integer.parseInt(object.getString("r_id").toString()));
                            Requests.add(userRequests);
                        }
      /*                  for(int i = 0; i < Requests.size(); i++) {
                            Log.d("request :", String.valueOf(Requests.));
                        }
        */                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
                        adapter = new RequestAdapter(getApplicationContext(), Requests,ViewRequests.this);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }

//                        Requests.add(userRequests);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("Volley Error:", error.getMessage());
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("user_id", "1");
                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ViewRequests.this);
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccepted() {
        extractRequest();
    }
}
```

Below is the adapter file which performs the operation on data stored on the MySQL stored on webserver which works well.

**RequestAdapter.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class RequestAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RequestAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<UserRequests> userRequest;
    Context ctx;
    ViewRequests activity;
    AcceptedCallback callback;

    public RequestAdapter(Context ctx, List<UserRequests> userRequest,AcceptedCallback callback) {
        this.ctx=ctx;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
        this.userRequest = userRequest;
        this.callback=callback;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.request_list_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final UserRequests ureq=userRequest.get(position);
            holder.usrname.setText(userRequest.get(position).getUsername());
            holder.pickup.setText(userRequest.get(position).getPickupaddress());
            holder.drop.setText(userRequest.get(position).getDropaddress());
        Picasso.get().load(userRequest.get(position).getImage()).into(holder.usrpic);//next here
        holder.accept.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               //Toast.makeText(ctx,"This is accept button"+String.valueOf(ureq.getId()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("id of transaction", String.valueOf(ureq.getId()));
                Log.d("position value", String.valueOf(userRequest.get(position)));

                accept(ureq.getId(), position);




            }
        });


    }

    private void accept(int id,int p) {
        RequestQueue queue= Volley.newRequestQueue(ctx);
        StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "xxxxx", new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                if(response.equals("accepted")){
                    Log.d("accepted","1 true");
                    Toast.makeText(ctx,"Accepted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    callback.onAccepted();

                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(ctx,response,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(ctx,error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params=new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("rid", String.valueOf(id));

                return params;
            }
        };   RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(ctx);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return userRequest.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
TextView usrname,pickup,drop;
ImageView usrpic;//here
        Button accept,reject;


        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            usrname=itemView.findViewById(R.id.R_L_tvusername);
            pickup=itemView.findViewById(R.id.R_L_tvpckpadd);
            drop=itemView.findViewById(R.id.R_L_tvdropadd);
            usrpic=itemView.findViewById(R.id.R_L_iv_display_image);
            accept=itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
            reject=itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
        }
    }

}
interface AcceptedCallback{
    void onAccepted();
}
```

**EDIT:** I want to refresh data after clicking on the accept button but the problem is the onclick event is defined inside adapter so I don't know how to call the method defined inside the ViewRequests.java
Is there any way to define the method in new class and return the list in the form of `List` fetched from the internet.
or
Is there any way to call async the method?

Answer (score 0):

its just a simple request, which is executed only once, in `onCreate`, so you have to repeat it every time you want to refresh data (e.g. in some interval)

```
private Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

private void extractDelayed(){
    h.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null); // clears out all previous Runnables
    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            extractRequest();
        }
    }, 5000); // run() will be called after 5 secs
}
```

call `extractDelayed` in `onPause` method and also in `onResponse` and in `onErrorResponse`

don't forget to clear out `Handler` when it isn't needed anymore, e.g. by putting below in `onPause` method

```
h.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
```

if you don't wan't to lose position then don't make `new RequestAdapter` every time, instead check if it's already set, if yes then make some method in adapter for setting your parsed data and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

edit: due to answer edit

at first make some callback interface defined in adapter, e.g.

```
public static interface AcceptedCallback{
    void onAccepted();
}
```

next make your `Activity` implements `AcceptedCallback`

```
public class ViewRequests extends AppCompatActivity implements AcceptedCallback {
```

and implement `onAccepted` method

```
public void onAccepted(){
    extractRequest();
}
```

now pass this interface reference to your adapter

```
public class RequestAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RequestAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<UserRequests> userRequest;
    Context ctx;
    ViewRequests activity;
    AcceptedCallback callback;

    public RequestAdapter(Context ctx, List<UserRequests> userRequest,
        AcceptedCallback callback) {
        this.ctx=ctx;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
        this.userRequest = userRequest;
        this.callback = callback;
    }
```

init in `Activity`

```
adapter = new RequestAdapter(getApplicationContext(), Requests, ViewRequests.this);
```

now you may call `callback.onAccepted()` inside adapter, e.g. in `onResponse`. it is defined in `Activity` and in there will fire starting data refresh

Comment: I have updated the thing which I want to achieve Please check

Comment: Tried the thing you updated but still list is not refreshing without restarting the activity

Comment: can you update your question with my code improvements? it should work, I've applied this pattern many times... or maybe put some `Log.d()` in next steps and check at which phase log isn't called

Comment: I have debugged it and it seems that `extractrequest()` method is not getting called

Comment: sadly now I don't have a clue... pattern is proper, it must work and there must be some small logic problem, but I don't see it... :( do you see `Log.d("accepted","1 true");` log? callback call is just two lines below, maybe put also in there some log before `extractRequest()` call?

Comment: you are NOT getting `Log.d("accepted","1 true");`? so the `response` isn't `"accepted"`, how `onAccepted` would be called then... inspect this `if` statement in `onResponse`, which `Toast` you are getting (put more text in it for differentiate)? do you know that `"accepted"` isn't same `String` value comparing to `"Accepted"`? letter case matters, white spaces at the begging and on the end also... maybe try with this `if (response.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).trim().equals("accepted")) {`

Comment: this accepted: 1 true is coming in toast data is manipuated at the server side but I tried is added another `Log.d()` inside `onaccepted()` method defined in ViewRequest.java. But it does not show the Log message written inside `onaccepted()` when it is called

Comment: last guess: paste `AcceptedCallback` declaration inside `RequestAdapter` (before last `{`, not after) and try to call `onAccepted()` at first line inside `onResponse`. don't have idea why it isn't firing, it very should, this is a very easy and logic pattern

Answer (score 0):

There can be many approaches:

1. If there is a change in database on server side, you can use of push notification. Whenever there is a change on server (or any other configuration you set) you can send push to registered devices. Upon receiving that push on device you can call your specific method to fetch the data.
2. You can set a timer, on behalf of that timer expiry you can call your method to fetch the data.

For reference, of second point I am sharing a sample code:

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) { //30000 max time of expiry
  public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
       extractRequest();
  }

  public void onFinish() {
  }
```

}.start();

Comment: I want to refresh data onclick of the accept button

Comment: then that is very smiple, why dont you call your method inside onclick event?

Comment: because the onclick event is inside requestadapter.java and extractrequest method is inside viewrequests.java

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SwipeRefreshLayout`

```
   swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {  
        @Override  
        public void onRefresh() {  
                   swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);  
                   //your code on swipe refresh  
                     
        }  
    });  
    swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(Color.RED);
```